# What if my screen resolution is less than layout resolution?

Tags: html, css

I try to make the area like this:

[image]

but the problem is that resolution of my screen is less then layout. What is the best way to shape it as in the layout? Do I have to use custom % or responsive table, what do you think?

Comment: you can responsive your page. no matter screen what resolution, it will show perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

You could divide your layout into two groups, each a sqare of 4x4. On vertical screen, the second group would wrap and be placed below. On horizontal screen, the groups are placed next to each other (same as in your picture).

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="item pic">
    <div class="item text">
    <div class="item pic">
    <div class="item text">
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="item pic">
    <div class="item text">
    <div class="item pic">
    <div class="item text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, on small screens make your `.group` element `100vw` and on larger screens it would be `50vw`.